# PHP Parse XML issues when XML has variables

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

Pls see snippet of XML file below:

```
<products>
<product>
<id>2589527</id>
<name>Samsung PS42C450</name>
<manufacturer>Samsung</manufacturer>
<manufacturer-id>22</manufacturer-id>
<description>42 in, Widescreen, Plasma, HD Ready, Samsung DNIe+ ,</description>
<category>Sound and Vision &gt; Vision &gt; TVs</category>
<category-id>2</category-id>
<number-of-retailers>16</number-of-retailers>
<image-url height="217" width="300">http://images.pricerunner.com/product/300x217/101294172/Samsung-PS42C450.jpg</image-url>
<rating type="average">
  <average>4,1</average>
</rating>
<rating type="professional">
  <average>4,1</average>
  <num-ratings>1</num-ratings>
</rating>
<lowest-price currency="GBP">354.44</lowest-price>
<highest-price currency="GBP">549.00</highest-price>
</product>
</products>
```

I'm having problems parsing image-url, lowest-price and highest-price

I'm trying:

```
$lowprice = $products->lowest-price;

$highprice = $products->highest-price;

$imageURL = $products->image-url;
```

But they are returning nothing - any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: $url = 'http://*********/feedoutput.xml';

$filecontent  = file_get_contents($url);

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("feed not loading");

foreach ($xml->product as $products) { etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use $products->{'lowest-price'}. (with curly braces you can use special characters such as the minus sign)

Shai.

Answer (score 1):

```
$products->lowest-price;
```

PHP will interpret as

```
($products->lowest)  minus price;
```

There's no "lowest" in your $products object, and `price` is almost certainly not a defined constant, so both show up as null, get cast to 0's, and end up producing `0-0=0`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of the dash (assuming other properties work). Try encapsulating them with curly braces, like

```
$products->{highest-price};
```

Comment: Aurimas, your example is looking for a key which is the result of highest minus price (an expression that doesn't exist) . When searching for a "stringed" key , you should use ' sign (like in my answer above' $products->{'highest-price'}

Comment: absolutely true, Shai, I missed it!

Answer (score 0):

There are (maybe) two unrelated issues.

**1. XML structure**

Your (broken) code, e.g. `$products->lowest-price` is *wanting* to access the `lowest-price` element which is a child of `$products`. Assuming the variable is named after the element, you have a little more work to do. The XML is structured like

```
<products>
 └─ <product>
     └─ <lowest-price>
```

So if `$products` is the `products> element, then three steps are needed.

```
$products->product->lowest-price
```

The above may be a non-issue, and simply unfortunate variable naming.

**2. Dash (-) in element name**

When presented with `$a->b-c`, PHP sees that as `$a->b <minus> c` as `b-c` is not a valid label (and no a valid object property name).  As noted on the "SimpleXML Basic usage" manual page ([link](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic)), the appropriate solution is to use the *variable property* syntax ala.

```
$products->product->{'lowest-price'}
```

See: http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic (Example #3)